# Angular formGroup, have specific validator for each value

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have a form with 3 value.

```
 this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        beginDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
        endDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
        username: ['', [Validators.required]],
      },
      { }
    );
```

I want to put a specific validator for each value so
beginDate should be 01.xx.xxxx (should always be the first of the month)
endDate should be 25.xx.xxxx (should always be the 25 of the month)
username should start with the 'p' letter.

What is the better way to do that ?
I can create a validators and check with if/else but it isn't really pretty:

```
this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        beginDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
        endDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
        username: ['', [Validators.required]],
      },
      { validator: this.checkValue}
    );
```

Is it a better way to have a validator for each value of my fromgroup ?

Comment: I think for the first 2 cases you can write a validator that only checks the day and provide the day to it as a parameter. For the 3rd case you probably want some kind of "startsWith" Validator. See https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators for more information

Comment: But how can i write two validator ? How can i have two different validator in my formBuilder ?

Comment: You can add validators to specific form controls by just adding them to the array of validators, e.g. `[Validators.required, yourValidator]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a custom validator like below.

```
function dayOfMonthValidator(date: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {
    [key: string]: boolean
  } | null => {
    let {  value } = control;
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(control.value) !== "[object Date]")
      value = Date.parse(value);
    return value.getDate() === date 
      ? null 
      : { "dayOfMonth": true   }
  };
}
```

and use it like below :

```
this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        beginDate: ['', [Validators.required,this.dayOfMonthValidator(1)]],
        endDate: ['', [Validators.required,,this.dayOfMonthValidator(25)]],
        username: ['', [Validators.required]],
      },      
    );
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-example-b98ahe?file=app/datepicker-filter-example.html)

Comment: So in my html i can just use {{testFrom.get('beginDate').validator}} ? It isn't working ..I already try with .invalid and .dirty

Comment: @Kan You'd do good reading the documentation. You can check for this specfic error with `testForm.get('beginDate').errors?.dayOfMonth`

Comment: @Kan added a stackblitz sample.